# Is this JS-Framework an Opensource Framework?

Tags: kineticjs, javascript-framework

I have found a JS-Framework KineticJS.
The Website is [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/)!.

This Framework is opensource?
Should I pay for it?

I want to use it for the website of my company.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> KineticJS JavaScript Framework http://www.kineticjs.com/ Copyright
>   2013, Eric Rowell Licensed under the **MIT or GPL Version 2** licenses.

Source: https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki/License

So yes, **it is an Open Source framework**, and as long as you comply with the license terms, **you don't have to pay for it** (not even for commercial use for you company website).